# Is there a vimscript function to wrap text?

Tags: vimscript, wrapping

Is there a vimscript function that wraps text in a similar manner like `gqgq` does?

For example, if I have the following string variable:

```
let txt = 'One foo, two bars and three bazes went up the hill'
```

I'd like to call something like:

```
let indent   = 4
let textwith = 12
let wrapped = wrap(txt, indent, textwidth)
```

After the call, the value of `wrapped` should be

```
    One foo, two
    bars and
    three bazes
    went up the
    hill
```

Is there something that does that?

Comment: While I didn't found any function, you could create one that paste the text into a buffer, operate over it (there you can `gq`) and copying it afterward.

Comment: I was thinking of that, too, but I am going this route only as last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function does what I need

```
fu! TextWrap(text, width, indent)

  let l:line = ''
  let l:ret  = ''

  for word in split(a:text)

    if len(l:line) + len(word) + 1 > a:width

       if len(l:ret)
          let l:ret .= "\n"
       endif
       let l:ret .=  repeat(' ', a:indent) . l:line

       let l:line = ''

    endif

    if len (l:line)
       let l:line .= ' '
    endif

    let l:line .= word

  endfor

  let l:ret .= "\n" . repeat(' ', a:indent) . l:line

  return l:ret

endfu
```

The function is then called, for example, like so

```
echo TextWrap("one two three four five six seven eight nine ten", 8, 2)
```

Which results in

```
  one two
  three
  four
  five six
  seven
  eight
  nine ten
```

The parameter `indent` specifies how many empty (space) characters there are in front of the first word. `width` specifies the maximum number of characters *after* `indent` characters. (for example `five six` or `nine ten` each constists of 8 characters).

Comment: Confused on the expected values to be passed in here. do you have an example of the arguments?

Assuming:

`text = "Lorem ipsum dolar sit...", 
width = 80, 
indent = ??`

Not sure what the value of indent would be here.

Comment: You must pass a value for indent.

Comment: Right, just wasn't sure what the indent value should be. Would indent be "\t" or " " or what is it used for. An example function call would be amazing.

Comment: I have added an example function call. (and discovered a bug in the function that I have now fixed)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such function and it wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Why so ? Can you add details for your answer please ?

Comment: VimL function work with datatypes and do not handle the current buffer. Therefore wrapping makes no sense for an string datatype. If you want to wrap in VimScript, use the existing normal mode commands.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I was not talking about wrapping in a buffer. Despite your assertion, such a function would make much sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote something a bit alike for indenting with options my mail texts (with a justify option). It's called `yaposting`:

- https://github.com/guyzmo/vim-yaposting

whithin it there's a mail format tool with enough parameters to do that:

- https://github.com/guyzmo/vim-yaposting/blob/master/pylibs/mail_format.py

and it is exposed as a function within the vimscript file to do so:

- https://github.com/guyzmo/vim-yaposting/blob/master/plugin/yaposting.vim#L113

Though I did that plugin a long time ago, before I actually understood vim. If I was to rewrite this plugin, I'd change it to have the python function work within `:set formatprg` with the parameters of how you want to setup your indentation given as either arguments to `set formatprg` or another global vim setting. And then use the traditional `gqap` (and eventually enable other `gq-` like shortcut to make it available.

But the right thing is to use the "standard" vi thing, which is `gqap`, and the right tool that formats things how you want it!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Vim's paragraph formatting abilities can be extended by installing an old program called 'par'.

```
:set formatprg=par\ -w12
" (gq will now format using par. Does not affect gw)

:map <A-q> {v}!par -w12<CR>
" (maps alt-q to format selection using par)
```

source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Par_text_reformatter

Comment: Not **terribly** old. Two and a half years since the last update isn't bad considering what it is. [Author's Web site is here](http://www.nicemice.net/par/).